# How to make an appointment and save it to database Flask?

Tags: python, flask, fullcalendar

I am making a small app where the client can make an appointment in a calendar, but I don't know how to save the appointment inside the database then show it to them after by date.

**Full Edit:**

I've created the calendar with some junk appointments as you can see below:

[image: Click to see a full image.]

I want to save the appointment inside the database, so when any client hits on any date after submitting it, an ajax request will be sent to my views where I can handle the request, here is the **view.py**:

```
@abonent_panel_route.route('/panel/make/appointment/')
@abonent_panel_route.route('/panel/make/appointment/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_appo():
    # user = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first_or_404()

    import json
    getData = str(request.args.getlist('data'))
    data  = json.loads(getData)

    if data :
        print "\n\n\n\n" + str(data['title']) + "\n\n\n\n"
        return jsonify({'success': data})
    else:
        print "\n\n\n\n" + str(len(data)) + "\n\n\n\n"
        return jsonify({'error': 'No data!'})
```

And here is the `javascript` code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var initialLocaleCode = 'ru';
    var d = new Date();
    var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
        },
        defaultDate: strDate,
        height: 650,
        locale: initialLocaleCode,
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            var eventData;
            if (title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                $(this).css({'background-color':'red'});
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{{url_for("panel_abonent.get_appo")}}',
                    data: [eventData]
                })
                .done(function(data){

                    if(data.error){
                        console.log(eventData);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(eventData);
                    }

                });
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },


        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: strDate
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2017-04-18',
                end: '2017-04-20'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2017-04-20'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2017-04-29'
            },
        ]
    });

    $.each($.fullCalendar.locales, function(localeCode) {
        $('#locale-selector').append(
            $('<option/>')
                .attr('value', localeCode)
                .prop('selected', localeCode == initialLocaleCode)
                .text(localeCode)
        );
    });

    $('#locale-selector').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'locale', this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Inside the console , I can see a list of data of the picked date, like title, start and end time, here it is:

```
Object {title: "asfawg", start: r, end: r}
start : r{
    "_ambigTime":true,
    "_ambigZone":true,
    "_d" : "Thu Apr 06 2017 06:00:00 GMT+0600 (+06)",
    "_fullCalendar":true,
    "_i":"2017/4/19",
    "_isAMomentObject":true,
    "_isUTC":true,
    "_isValid":true,
    "_locale":e,
    "_offset":0,
    "_pf":Object,
    "__proto__":Object,
    "title":"asfawg"
}
```

In **view.py**, I've converted the dictionary to a list to make it easy to fetch the data from the list, so you have a key and the value, as you've seen above where I print the title **print "\n\n\n\n" + str(data['title']) + "\n\n\n\n"** I should get the value of the title which is **asfawg**, but I got nothing and the request always return **No data.** and the **length** of the list returns **0**.

Please , anybody tells me where is the mistake that I've made.

Comment: just after `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);` you can make an ajax call to your server-side function, containing the event data you want to save. Simple enough.

Comment: Thanks dude for your interest. 
The problem is i can't get the picked date from the calendar, so for example today i want to make an appointment, so today is 2017/04/18, all i got is just the comment i can't get the date and save it to database !!

Comment: I got a big list containing the eventData !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Why do you need the picked date from the calendar? At the point in the code I mentioned, you have already got all the event data, including the start and end dates selected by the user, inside the `eventData` variable. You can send all this to the server, it should be enough to save the event so it can be re-displayed in future. Anyway, I don't know python at all, but `request.args.getlist('eventData')` looks wrong to me - there's unlikely to be one single POST value called `eventData`, more likely a list of all the properties of `eventData` as separate vars.

Comment: ...cont'd: Check your browser's network tab to see what's actually submitted in the request body and then match your server-side code accordingly.

Comment: I tried what you've mentioned above but nothing worked, always i got an empty list !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem, the eventData itself was a dictionary not a list.

So if i want to fetch the start date for example inside ajax request then to send it to my **view.py**, i would do something like:

```
data: {
    'data': title,
    'start': eventData['start']['_d'],
    'end': eventData['end']['_d']
}
```

And I've changed a little bit my views, i added a function that took any json argument and return it as a json dictionary, i used `flask_restful` to do the job, here is the function:

```
def parse_arg_from_requests(arg, **kwargs):

    from flask_restful import reqparse
    parse = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parse.add_argument(arg, **kwargs)
    args = parse.parse_args()
    return args[arg]
```

Next is very simple, just get the arguments one by one like the following order:

```
data = parse_arg_from_requests('data')
start = parse_arg_from_requests('start')
end = parse_arg_from_requests('end')
return render_template('panel/panel.html')
```

Comment: do you have a full example in github or some repository?